24MHz Clock Signal Distortion
I am measuring a 3.3 V 24.576 MHz clock signal coming from a CDCE913. The signal is used to drive 25 audio TDM receivers. The line is terminated in series with a 33 ohm resistor at the transmitter end (the CDCE913). The waveform doesn't look as expected, and I'm not sure what the most likely cause could be. Here is what it looks like:

I used a 100MHz oscilloscope from Siglent (SDS2104X) with a 200MHz probe. I try to keep the probe grounding as short as possible with the supplied spring grounding (~10mm).
What could be the cause and how can I improve the signal?
EDIT: Here is a block diagram and a measurement taken at various points on the board (the blue triangles are the clock signal receivers):


What does the transmission line consist of? Does it have 33 ohms characteristic impedance? Why did you not terminate the far end?

You're driving 25 receivers from a single transmitter? That can be difficult. Please show a schematic.

What's the line topology? Where are you probing? Post a physical diagram detailing lengths of line between nodes, and what those nodes are connected to.

Take a measurement with a 1X probe and post.

@JohnBirckhead What would that achieve? What would you see with 1x probe, a flat DC line at half-supply?

@JohnBirckhead - A 1X probe has too much capacitance to be used to probe this. Typically a 1X probe presents ~100pF load.

I believe you are seeing the oscillation caused by a combination of the trace inductance and the capacitance.  If this is true, part of the capacitance is contributed by the scope probe, and I would think that switching to 1X will change the shape of the signal, giving a hint that this is the case.

He might also try measuring the signal at different points along the path.

Erm, you are splitting one logic level output to a bus with 25cm in length and split off 5 branches, each 25cm in length with 5 receivers per branch. I'd say, given the setup, the waveform looks approximately what I would expect.

With all those branches and receivers, you have quite an echo chamber.

One way to avoid that is to use multiple output clock buffers and create a clock tree where each clock line is point to point.

Okay, so what other options besides clock buffers do I have to mitigate this problem? I used the impedance calculator to get a rough 50 ohm impedance on the traces for the PCB.

The individual traces may be 50 ohms, but each split puts two 50 ohm lines in parallel, resulting in 25 ohms and a big reflection.  If you want 50 ohms constant impedance and don't want to use clock buffers, get rid of the splits and put everything in a line with termination at the end. Note that you'll want to look at the impedance of each TDM receiver before committing to this.

What clock skew is tolerable between each receiver?

It looks exactly as expected. There is a lot of paths for echo to be reflected back and forth through the length of each column and its lateral feed, and these echoes will propagate past the driver laterally. Those echoes are the source waveform, shifted in time, and overlaid, multiple times. They add to each other, creating the steps. The distance between the steps is related to the length of the stubs.
What you're measuring is the equivalent of this, except there is a whole bunch of pipelines, and they have different lengths, and instead of a saxophone there is a sub-bass organ pipe running at 10Hz or so.

Okay, so what other options besides clock buffers do I have to mitigate this problem?

There are no simpler options. Yours is exactly the problem the clock buffers have been designed to solve. A simple clock buffer IC with multiple outputs is not somehow "complicated". Furthermore, such a clock buffer regenerates all clocks using a PLL, and has a programmable phase. That way you can make the phase of all the clock copies identical in the middle of the length of each column or half-column, ensuring - hopefully - that the TDM data setup and hold times won't be violated.
Furthermore, I wouldn't call what you see a "problem". Any decent signal integrity text would have elucidated clock tree drive issues. You just weren't aware of it and chose an approach that stood no chance. Take your losses and move on. You will be spinning new PCBs no matter what. Thankfully, today it costs much less than it did just a couple decades ago. Back then, re-spinning a 4 layer board could ruin a small business. Today, it will merely sting.
The solution would be similar to fixing the problem with sound and the pipelines. First, you'll have to isolate each of the "pipelines" or columns: drive them individually using a multi-output PLL clock conditioner that can compensate for the various length of the lateral feed from the conditoner to the columns. The columns must be driven with (at one end) and terminated (at the other) in their characteristic impedance.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The termination may be less critical when the column are cut by half: instead of driving their full length from one end, drive each half-column from the middle:

simulate this circuit
Shown above are general approaches. You'll definitely want to simulate your actual circuit using SPICE and transmission line models. To make sure the simulation is representative of reality, you should first recreate the problem you're seeing using SPICE. You may end up having to use IBIS models of the clock driver outputs and of the TDM chip clock inputs. This will save some time over manually tweaking the driver and receiver spice model to match observed behavior.

Thank you very much for the detailed answer! That helped a lot. I have a few more questions: would soldering a resistor to each branch help? If I am using a clock buffer for the next design, how should I terminate each branch (parallel termination at the end?)? Do I have to terminate at the 'end' of the branch or should I have a termination resistor at each receiver? Would you also assume that a clock buffer for the 96kHz line would be beneficial for performance (jittr, noise…) ?

Hi, I just wanted to thank you. The first solution you suggested did work. I reworked the circuit boards by scraping off some of the solder mask and connecting them to the clock buffer. Thanks a lot.
